# State change detection then while loop

Tags: arduino, state

I would like to stop DC motors after the counter reaches a value e,g num=3 (HIGH's) as shown in the following image:

[image: image showing robot direction]

White line is 3cm thick, black box 30cm squared!

The two IR sensors, `int rightSens=30`; and `int leftSens=32;` are working and give a `1` on sensing a black surface, and `0` on any other, i.e. white and in the absence of anything.

I would like the robot to count as in my loop, 3 LOWs incase counting white or 2 HIGHs incase of counting black,then do something e.g. stop, as shown with the while loop.

Something must be wrong, it seems like not counting because it doesn't stop after passing 3 boxes or 3 white lines. any help very appreciated!

```cpp
int pwm=2;     //initializing pin 2 as pwm
int leftMotorin_1=22;//right
int leftMotorin_2=24;
int pwm2=3;     
int rightMotorin_3=26;
int rightMotorin_4=28;

//sensor
int rightSens=30;
int leftSens=32;
int rightSensState;
int leftSensState;

//Variables for counting lines
int previousState=0;
int currentState=0;

void setup ()
{
  pinMode(pwm,OUTPUT);  // set pwm pin as output
  pinMode(leftMotorin_1,OUTPUT); //logic pins are also set as output
  pinMode(leftMotorin_2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwm2,OUTPUT);  // set pwm pin as output
  pinMode(rightMotorin_3,OUTPUT); //logic pins are also set as output
  pinMode(rightMotorin_4,OUTPUT);

  //pinMode(obSens,INPUT);
  pinMode(rightSens,INPUT);
  pinMode(leftSens,INPUT);
}
void readSensors()
{
  rightSensState = digitalRead(rightSens);
  leftSensState = digitalRead(leftSens);
}
void moveForward()
{
  digitalWrite(leftMotorin_1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorin_2,LOW);
  analogWrite(pwm,150);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorin_3,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorin_4,LOW);
  analogWrite(pwm2,150);
}
void stopWheels()
{
  //For brake
  digitalWrite(leftMotorin_1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorin_2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorin_3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorin_4,LOW);
}
void loop()
{
  int count=0;
  int num=3;
  moveForward(); 
  readSensors();
  (currentState=(leftSensState && rightSensState));
  if (currentState != previousState );
  {
    if (currentState==HIGH)
      count++;
    previousState=currentState;
  }

  while (count!=num) { 
    moveForward(); 
    readSensors();
    (currentState=(leftSensState && rightSensState));
    if (currentState != previousState );
    {
      if (currentState==HIGH)
        count+=1;
      previousState=currentState;
    }
    if (counter == num)
    {
      stopWheels();
      delay(20);
      break;
    }  
  }                                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: The variables `rightSensState` and `leftSensState` are not declared anywhere!! You must declare them as global (or declare them local and pass them through functions). I think your current code won't even compile because of this reason.

Comment: Not sure why you have the `while` loop inside your loop() function.  Think about how the loop() function works in the Arduino environment - what happens after your `while` loop exits...

Comment: @ Sembei Norimaki, i have declared the rightSensState and leftSensState as global variables so the program compiles, but still seems not to count

Comment: @ Jeff Loughlin. after while loop the robot should stop and turn right to continue with other tasks. but first i need it to be to count either the HIGHs or the LOWs to make it stop